# Can I use higher caps for input/output of MCP1700?

Tags: voltage-regulator, decoupling-capacitor

I'm battery powered (4xAA ~= 5.5V) and use the MCP1700 to regulate to 3.3V. Expected load is ~100mA. The datasheet says to use 1uF caps between input/output and ground. I only have either 10uF or 100nF available.

Is that OK to use higher caps (the 10uF)? Same for input and output?

Comment: Devil is in the details here. Bad/cheap ones have their loop tuned for a particular output capacitor value and ESR. Good ones are happy with anything above minimum required. Check the datasheet and if it's still unclear, ask the manufacturer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on [MCP1700 datasheet](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/MCP1700-Low-Quiescent-Current-LDO-20001826E.pdf):

Input capacitor of 1uF is recommended for most applications. Larger values can be used to improve AC performance.

Output capacitor of 1uF is required for typical applications. It also says ceramic, tantalum, or aluminum electrolytic are supported. ESR must be between 0 and 2 ohms.

So it looks like you could use 10uF on both input and output.

However, if you don't know what kind of 10uF capacitors you have and what their ESR is, they may not be suitable.

Also it is unknown if the other parts of the circuit can handle 10uF caps even if the regulator can. So you should not look at the regulator in isolation but the whole system.